# Method to add row to sqlite3 table is not working - with SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have built an app using flask, and am using flask-user to handle my users.

I am using a sqlite3 database. There is a problem with the functions to delete and add new users:

```
def delete_user(username):
    if User.query.filter(User.username == username).first():
        user = User.query.filter(User.username == username).first()
        db.session.delete(user)
        db.session.commit()
delete_user('bobby')

def create_user(username,password,role):
    if not User.query.filter(User.username == username).first():
        user = User(
            username=username,
            password=user_manager.hash_password(password)
        )
        user.roles.append(Role(name=role))
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
create_user('ollie','password','admin')
```

It successfully deletes 'bobby' but doesn't add 'ollie'. 
The create_user() **does** work, if the database is removed before the code is run. But not otherwise. I have also tried to comment out `# db.create_all()`

Before the functions above, is the models section:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    active = db.Column('is_active', db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='1')

    username =.Column(db.String(50, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, server_default='')

    # Define the relationship to Role via UserRoles
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles') 

# Define the Role data-model
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

# Define the UserRoles association table
class UserRoles(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('roles.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))

# Setup Flask-User
user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)
db.create_all()
```

Comment: "The create_user() does work, if the database is removed before the code is run" — `username` is defined as unique in your model. Are you somehow (even though you have the check) trying to add the same user twice? Also the role names are unique, does it fail on that? Do you get any errors? If so, include the traceback in the question.

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä. I get no errors at all, it just doesn't add to the db -> select * from users; (= nothing). I agree, I think the issue is with the role names being unique. However, when I set name to unique = False (class Role). This doesn't sort the issue. Create_user only works (still) if the roles are different.